# Как создать pptp соединение с динамическим ip?

Tags: linux, ppp

Настраиваю pptp соединение на сервере, а оно всегда создается с одним и тем же ip-адресом 
Вот **ifconfig**:

```
 Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
       inet addr:192.168.10.2  P-t-P:192.168.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
       UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Metric:1</blockquote>
```

Даже, если я сделаю 10 подключений на 10-ти разных интерфейсах 192.168.10.2 будет всегда. Мне нужно, что бы 192.168.10.2 менялся. Как это сделать?

**Полный ifconfig**

```
ppp6      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
      inet addr:192.168.10.2  P-t-P:192.168.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Metric:1
      RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
      RX bytes:88 (88.0 B)  TX bytes:82 (82.0 B)

ppp7      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
      inet addr:192.168.10.2  P-t-P:192.168.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
      RX bytes:104 (104.0 B)  TX bytes:98 (98.0 B)

ppp8      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
      inet addr:192.168.10.2  P-t-P:192.168.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
      RX bytes:104 (104.0 B)  TX bytes:98 (98.0 B)

ppp9      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
      inet addr:192.168.10.2  P-t-P:192.168.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1446  Metric:1
      RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
      RX bytes:88 (88.0 B)  TX bytes:82 (82.0 B)</blockquote>
```

Comment: А зачем вам разные адреса ? И кстати что вы используете для поднятия pptp. потому как можно напряму использовать pptpctrl, а можно через демона. Тут скорее странно, почему у вас p-t-p адрес всегда один и тот же

Comment: на другом хостинг-провайдере были разные адреса. Каждый раз разные. А теперь один и тот же. Файл /etc/pptpd.conf вообще отсутствует
Использую: pptpsetup --create tunnel --server 19...
разные адреса не особо нужны, нужно пустить трафик через разные интерфейсы. Раньше это удавалось командой:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ip сервера -o ppp0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.10.2
Но теперь все адреса приняли вид 192.168.10.2 и эта команда более не актуальна.
Если в ней менять интерфейсы (eth0 на eth1 и т.д.) ничего не происходит

Comment: Так, т.е. у вас клиентская сторона pptp линка ... вообще адрес который  на соединении на вашем конце обычно назначается сервером при подключении. А сервер его назначает либо динамически, либо статически в зависимости от имени пользователя. Надо включать отладку (добавляя debug в какой нибудь конфиг в /etc/ppp) и смотреть потом логи, что бы понять откуда берется адрес. и возможно потом смотреть логи на серверной стороне

Comment: ну у меня сервер и клиент - это одна система. То есть существует vpn (ip:login:pass). Я подключаюсь к нему с linux сервера и создаю туннель и создается интерфейс ppp1, который уже имеет локальные адреса 192.168... Раньше адреса генерировались автоматически, а теперь один и тот же... Ну или я вас не понял

Comment: pptpsetup создает туннель с клиентской стороны. На серверной стороне линка стоит pptpd или pptpctrl - вот они и отвечают за ip адреса. И кстати зачем pptp туннели в пределах одной системы

Comment: был не прав. Все таки у меня клиент. Так как без pptpd (его установки в linux)все работает. Подключаюсь через pptpsetup и туннель создается на новом интерфейсе. А вот как сделать динамические ip не пойму...

Comment: ничего не выходит. Все равно один и тот же ip адрес. Думаю, дело в конфиге сервера (поменял хостинг провайдера). Но я хочу научится настраивать на любом.
Раз не выходит изменить ip, то как перенаправлять весь трафик не через ip, а через интерфейс?
Раньше я настраивал все так: 
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
ip route add tab 2 default via 192.168.1.1 src 192.168.10.2 
ip rule add prio 100 fwmark 0x2/0x2 lookup 2  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ip моего сервера -o ppp0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.10.2 
Как перенаправлять через ppp0, ppp1,ppp2 и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

согласно `man pppd`, в качестве одной из опций можно передать адреса для создаваемого туннеля:

```
<local_IP_address>:<remote_IP_address>
```

можно указать оба адреса, можно любой из них опустить. наличие такой опции обычно никак не влияет на работоспособность туннеля: он ведь point-to-point (сокращённо *ppp*), т.е. пакеты «не промажут» мимо второго конца туннеля.

примеры:

```
 1.2.3.4:
 1.2.3.4:5.6.7.8
 :5.6.7.8
```

---

эта опция перекрывает настройки, передаваемыми «серверной» стороной.

кстати, если «та» сторона не передаёт такие настройки (и вы не использовали описываемую опцию в своей конфигурации), то интерфейсу присваиваются умолчальные адреса, заданные при компиляции *pppd*. см., например: https://superuser.com/q/624477/454489

---

относительно вашего случая — тут одно из двух:

- либо у вас в каком-нибудь конфигурационном файле, используемом *pppd*-емоном, явно указано `192.168.10.2:` или `192.168.10.2:192.168.1.1`
- либо, скорее, именно такую информацию передаёт *pppd*, запущенный на «той» стороне, вашему *pppd* при соединении.

уточнить можно в логах подключения (лучше добавить опции `dump debug` для получения бо́льших подробностей).

Comment: у меня этот тоже не работает. В chap-secrets я указывал # client server secret   IP addresses
user123 tunnel pass 192.168.55.55
Но ip все равно выдается 192.168.10.2. ЧТо бы я не делал...

Comment: Вот скриншот лога при debug: http://joxi.ru/n2YeQOkSjnMaa2

Comment: подскажите в каком. Где скажете, я там и пропишу. Я уже все конфиги перерыл, но найти, где прописать ip не знаю

Comment: уточнение (из-за склероза — много лет уже не сталкивался с ppp): «провайдерские» файлы ищутся в /etc/ppp/peers, а не в /etc/ppp.

Comment: Вот содержимое "провайдерского" файла. Что в нем изменить, что бы мне давался другой ip?
tunnel:# written by pptpsetup
pty "pptp 111.111.111.111 --nolaunchpppd" #айпи к которому коннекчусь
lock
noauth
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
name user12
remotename tunnel
ipparam tunnel
require-mppe-128

И как ставить enter тут, а то клавишей не работает и все в одну строку сливается

Comment: // 111.111.111.111 — это подконтрольная вам машина? - нет, это ip адрес vpn к которому я коннекчусь. 111.111.111.111:login:pass

Comment: pptpsetup --create tunnel --server 111.111.111.111 --username user12 --password mypass --encrypt --start \\ я создаю соединение этой командой. Создается новый интерфейс (ppp) и устанавливается соединение. Но файл tunnel в ppp\peers перезаписывается. (то есть айпи, который я там прописал не был задействован и после ввода команды строка исчезла)...

Comment: так запускайте уже pppd напрямую - а оно не запускает :). После ввода команды ничего не происходит. Убрал ip - запустило. debug ничего не показывает

Comment: http://joxi.ru/J2b6R31I4Bxqe2 - pppd call...//peers/tunnel:

# written by pptpsetup
pty "pptp 111.111.111.111 --nolaunchpppd"
lock
noauth
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
name user12
remotename tunnel
ipparam tunnel
require-mppe-128
192.168.10.22:192.168.1.1

Comment: Вы просили написать содержимое файла peers/tunnel и вывод команды. Я Вам сбросил конец вывода команды  и содержимое файла. Чего именно не хватает? Вывод команды занимает 260 строк. Как лучше вам сбросить его? А тут тут все в одну строку сольется

Comment: Добавил: На всех ссылках одно и тоже. (действительны по 1 разу):
https://privnote.com/uVxRXWnP#KumCkCkgz https://privnote.com/khvN4gjx#royOQhd5C https://privnote.com/adK65wYU#LW9ZLmH8L https://privnote.com/uiNuDIRu#RXAaUC7SS

Comment: 1. по вашим ссылкам ничего не отображается. вероятно, требуется запускать java-скрипты. 2. содержимое файла /etc/ppp/peers/tunnel вы в текст вопроса так и не добавили. 3. удачи!

Comment: содержимое файла я добавил в одном из предыдущих постов.
Вывод команды: http://pastie.org/10759620 // содержимое файла: http://paste.debian.net/415203/